# simplified htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/host
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/host/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?seg1=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?seg1=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3
```

my questions, is there a simplified .htaccess for those code?
thanks!

Comment: You need only one `RewriteEngine On` statement per `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your PHP can process empty parameters correctly then why not

```
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3
```

instead of the six rules?

So /a will generate index.php?seg1=a&seg2=&seg3=

Comment: sorry, i'm a newby.. how i wrote those code in .htaccess? like this: ?

    `RewriteEngine On`
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/host`
    `RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/host/$1 [R=301,L]`
    `RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?(-\w]+)?/?([-\w]]+)?/?$ index.php?seg1=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3` 

it return error for http://localhost/host/page/about/

Comment: You are missing a [ before the second `-\w`.  See the regexp_checker on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules if you want to debug your regexps