# Url rewrite not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, modx

My .htaccess is as below, and I need example.com/updatetagsyncronize.html/1/2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> example.com/updatetagsyncronize.html - it works like this

And i need

> example.com/updatetagsyncronize.html/1/2 - with two extra parameters

I found how to simplify and use with multiple parameters here [simplified htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556721/simplified-htaccess)

But it is not working

```
 RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?$ index.php?q=$1&seg2=$2&seg3=$3
```

What is the meaning of this **(.*)** and **([-\w]+)** How can i rewrite this, combine first, because i am using *cms modx*, and maybe that why i am facing errors. 
Any advice or links. Thanks!!!

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you make your document "updatetagsyncronize.html" a container (just "updatetagsyncronize") by checking corresponding checkbox in document's settings pane, here is the regexp that matches your string:

```
^([-\w\.]+)?\/?([-\w]+)?\/?([-\w]+)?\/?([-\w]+)?\/?$
// example.com/updatetagsyncronize/1/2/ or example.com/updatetagsyncronize/1/2
```

Also you need to enable friendly URLs in modx system settings. Or

```
^([-\w\.]+)?\/?([-\w\.]+)?\/?([-\w]+)?\/?([-\w]+)?\/?$
```

if you stick with ".html"

Comment: Good. Also make sure that other pages work too and pay attention to the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786340/rewrite-url-with-htaccess-for-multiple-parameters You might need to set that rewrite rule separately to handle your specific requests (.../1/2/ part)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the CustomRequest extra, if you are using MODX Revolution. Available in the extras repository.